# Can I legally fetch tweets without twitter API?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

I am doing an RSS notifier, but I would like to add Twitter and Facebook feeds in it.

as both social networks shut down their RSS services, I am fetching the content

directly from the HTML public pages, parsing the content I want.

Question is: Is what I am doing legal?

 Can I be sued for "stealing" information from their website?

PS: I know I could use Facebook or Twitter's API, but I don't want to log-in to their services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Twitter's terms](https://twitter.com/tos?lang=en) says the following:

> Except as permitted through the Twitter Services, these Terms, or the
> terms provided on dev.twitter.com, you have to use the Twitter API if
> you want to reproduce, modify, create derivative works, distribute,
> sell, transfer, publicly display, publicly perform, transmit, or
> otherwise use the Twitter Services or Content on the Twitter Services.
>
> [...]
>
> You may not do any of the following while accessing or using the
> Services: (i) access, tamper with, or use non-public areas of the
> Services, Twitter’s computer systems, or the technical delivery
> systems of Twitter’s providers; (ii) probe, scan, or test the
> vulnerability of any system or network or breach or circumvent any
> security or authentication measures; (iii) access or search or attempt
> to access or search the Services by any means (automated or otherwise)
> other than through our currently available, published interfaces that
> are provided by Twitter (and only pursuant to the applicable terms and
> conditions), unless you have been specifically allowed to do so in a
> separate agreement with Twitter (NOTE: crawling the Services is
> permissible if done in accordance with the provisions of the
> robots.txt file, however, **scraping the Services without the prior
> consent of Twitter is expressly prohibited)**; (iv) forge any TCP/IP
> packet header or any part of the header information in any email or
> posting, or in any way use the Services to send altered, deceptive or
> false source-identifying information; or (v) interfere with, or
> disrupt, (or attempt to do so), the access of any user, host or
> network, including, without limitation, sending a virus, overloading,
> flooding, spamming, mail-bombing the Services, or by scripting the
> creation of Content in such a manner as to interfere with or create an
> undue burden on the Services.

[facebook is a bit harsher:](https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php)

> 2. You will not engage in Automated Data Collection without Facebook's express written permission.

So just go and use the APIs meant for the explicit purpose of automatic data collection.

Comment: thank you very much for this fast reply!
it seems like I will have to keep my project for personal use.